# Invalid generated code while compiling template 'web.ViewSwitcherButton' odoo

Tags: odoo-14

```
Traceback:
Error: Invalid generated code while compiling template 'web.ViewSwitcherButton': missing ) after argument list
    at QWeb._compile (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:971:133)
    at Object.atNodeEncounter (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:1056:140)
    at QWeb._compileNode (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:990:54)
    at QWeb._compileChildren (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:1027:108)
    at QWeb._compileNode (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:997:6)
    at Object.atNodeEncounter (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:1066:44)
    at QWeb._compileNode (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:990:54)
    at QWeb._compileChildren (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:1027:108)
    at QWeb._compileNode (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:997:6)
    at QWeb._compileChildren (http://****/web/content/112-34b6e20/web.assets_common.js:1027:108)
```

This message appears on all pages and we cannot do anything.

When I activate developer mode with assets, it works fine.

Comment: This happens to me when I edit odoo code by mistake, verify that all files in the `web` module are unmodified.

Comment: It was working fine, but after the daily update, this error appeared. apt-get upgrade 01/03/2021

Comment: Because when you activate developer mode with assets it works fine, try to regenerate assets from the debug menu.

Comment: Great! The error was resolved, my gratitude to you

Answer (score 1):

I also face same problem when i using Odoo version 14.0-20210305. The problem is from file odoo/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml.

I try take base.xml from stable version in my case i take from version 14.0-20210108. Then i replace to new version.

Here part code of stable version:

```
<t t-name="web.ViewSwitcherButton" owl="1">
    <button type="button"
        t-att-accesskey="view.accessKey"
        t-attf-class="btn btn-secondary fa fa-lg o_switch_view o_{{ view.type }} {{ view.icon }}"
        t-att-class="{ active: env.view.type === view.type }"
        t-attf-aria-label="View {{ view.type }}"
        t-attf-title="View {{ view.type }}"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        tabindex="-1"
        t-on-click="trigger('switch-view', { view_type: view.type })"
    />
</t>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you activate developer mode with assets it works fine, then try to upgrade web module!

Comment: I already try this. This is only can solve for database that we use. But it will get error again when create new database again. For permanent solution u can read my solution.

Comment: How can I upgrade the web module?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fo the solution this helps and work for me too.

This is located as a bug you can check the error here.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/68040

Regards!